# Printing a div form with data to a page

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I have a div (divcontents) containing a form that has several questions and input textboxes for users to enter their answers.  I also have a button to show and hide my answers for each input textboxes (the textboxes will change colors when I click this button to reveal/hide the answers).

I've created a print module to help me print this div form:

```
function printContent(){
            var divno = document.getElementById("divpageno").value;

            var divcontents = document.getElementById(divno).innerHTML;
            var frame1 = document.createElement('iframe');
            frame1.name = "frame1";
            frame1.style.position = "absolute";
            frame1.style.top = "-1000000px";
            document.body.appendChild(frame1);
            var frameDoc = frame1.contentWindow ? frame1.contentWindow : frame1.contentDocument.document ? frame1.contentDocument.document : frame1.contentDocument;

            frameDoc.document.open();
            frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');

            frameDoc.document.write('<style>h1 { display: none;}');
            frameDoc.document.write('h0 { font-size: 8.0rem; line-height: 8.0rem;}');                      
            frameDoc.document.write('</style>');
            frameDoc.document.write('</head><body>');
            frameDoc.document.write(divcontents);
            frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
            frameDoc.document.close();
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.frames["frame1"].focus();
                window.frames["frame1"].print();
                document.body.removeChild(frame1);
            }, 500);
            return false;
}
```

The problem is that it will not show the users' answer when I try to print.  It will however show the textbox color changes.  I must be missing something very obvious but I can't seen to figure out what it is.

Comment: Did you mean to use `printContent()` instead of `print()`?

Comment: I only know of one function that will print a page and that is print(), printcontent() doesn't work.

Comment: I still can't figure out a way to print my form data. All input text content remains blanks :-(

Comment: I found the solution for this problem.  Basically the current method will allow me to reconstruct my screen form to a printable form, but it doesn't include form data entered by the user.  This requires an additional javascript loop to re-read those data into the printable form.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this problem. Basically the current method will allow me to reconstruct my screen form to a printable form, but it doesn't include form data entered by the user. This requires an additional javascript loop to re-read the form data elements into the printable form elements like in this example:

while (document.getElementById('word_id_' + word_page + '_' + id_start_num))

{
frameDoc.document.getElementById('word_id_' + word_page + '_' + id_start_num).value = document.getElementById('word_id_' + word_page + '_' + id_start_num).value;

id_start_num++;
}

This works for me.